# issue with php sql no database selected

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have been created the database CSCW and I am unsure of why I keep getting the error, 'No database selected' I am a beginner so any help is a bonus! Thank You!

```
<html>
<head>
<title>CS coursework</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Online Stock Help.</h1>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "CSCW";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

//create db tables
$sql = "CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    businessName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50),
    regDate TIMESTAMP
)
";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Table Created Successfully";
}  else {
    echo "Unsuccessful: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to use `DATETIME` instead of `TIMESTAMP` as it represents a larger range of values. `VARCHAR(50)` is way too short for an email address, and likewise a limit of 30 for name is puny. You really should stick with `INT` and `VARCHAR(255)` as defaults unless you have a very compelling reason. Seeing `INT(6)` here is really odd.

Comment: You need to pass in the database name in the connection string or you won't be connected to any particular database.

Comment: I'm sure you'll find there are no usages of `$dbname`.

Comment: @tadman that has done it thank you so much!

Comment: You should add the code necessary to make this work in a  answer if you got it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

The correct code is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>CS coursework</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Online Stock Help.</h1>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "CSCW";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

//create db tables
$sql = "CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    businessName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50),
    regDate TIMESTAMP
)
";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Table Created Successfully";
}  else {
    echo "Unsuccessful: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your connection is missing the database name
change the connection line to 
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);